# what is the full form of `it's` in the following below

Tags: word-form

What is the full form of "it's" in the following below?

> I hate this weather. **It's** been raining all week!

Comment: Here's the [Merriam-Webster definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/it%27s). Which one do you think is appropriate here?

Comment: I think `It has` because it is a present perfect continuous tense following.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Thank you for the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate this weather. It has been raining all week!

Comment: Thank you, I got it.